# How to send the time of a form being submitted to servlet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets, timestamp

Please have a look at the below code

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var text = document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value;
        var action = $("form")[0].action;
        action = action+"?date="+new Date();
        alert(action);
    });
});
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>        


        <form name="test" method="post" action="B">
            <input name="text" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">


        </form>
```

I am trying to attach the time of the form being submitted to the URL, before it is being sent to the servlet. But evrytime in my servlet, the time is not showing and in the browser URL also the `date` variable is not displayed.

My servlet code is below for the reference

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try
        {
            String print=request.getParameter("date");
            out.print(print);
        } finally
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

How can I send  the time of the form being submitted to URL either via URL or via any other method?

Comment: Your form will get submitted even before the date value is set and passed along form. Instead you can change the submit button into normal button and onclick of the button you can set date and then submit the form.

Comment: if you need the timestamp of form submit why would that needs to be set on client side you can even achieve this on the server side with first line of code in your method as timestamp at which the request reaches the server. This is my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

These lines:

```
var action = $("form")[0].action;
action = action+"?date="+new Date();
```

...just update your `action` variable. That variable has no ongoing connection to the form's `action` property.

You also don't need to look up the form again, it's `this` in your `submit` callback.

To update the form's `action` property, you'd have to assign to it:

```
this.action = this.action + "?" + encodeURIComponent(new Date());
```

Note that that will send the date in a browser-dependent format, which is not likely to be useful. Instead, perhaps:

```
this.action = this.action + "?" + encodeURIComponent(new Date().toISOString());
```

---

Separately, you're doing this in a `submit` handler. It may be worth double-checking that that is early enough on your various target browsers. If not, do it on the `submit` button's `click` instead:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    this.form.action = this.form.action + "?" + encodeURIComponent(new Date().toISOString());
});
```

---

Or, as an alternative to appending it to the URL, you could have a hidden field in the form:

```
<input name="date" type="hidden">
```

...which you fill in from the `submit` handler:

```
$(this).find("input[name=date]").val(new Date().toISOString());
```

---

Side note: **All** information sent from the client can be spoofed, so take the date/time you receive with a grain of salt. In particular, you can't rely on it to know when the form was actually sent. To know that, use code on the *server* that records the date/time it was received, which will only be milliseconds later.

Comment: Regarding the last comment, actually what we need is the time the record created, which should be the time of the user, not the server. So, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @TeranceWijesuriya: Once the record is created, return that date/time to the client in the ISO-8601 format [subset that JavaScript supports](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format), and have the client create a `Date` from that ISO string -- the resulting `Date` object will have various methods (`getHours` and such) giving you the date/time in local time (and also `getUTCHours` and such giving you the date/time in UTC). Be sure the string you send back has a timezone, otherwise you get into browser-specific hassles. IE8 not supported. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the correct ID to the form add a hidden input;

```
<input id="clientDate" name="clientDate" type="hidden">
```

and use:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
   $("#clientDate").val(new Date()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a hidden field to capture date:

```js
var putDate = function(form) {
  form.date.value = new Date().toString();
};
```

```html
<form name="test" method="post" action="B" onsubmit="putDate(this);">
  <input name="text" type="text" />
  <input name="date" type="hidden" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```